# Sql table relation and distinct count

Tags: sql, database, count

I Have two tables:

1- **Personale**

- Name
- Persoanl_ID

2- **Presenze**

- Persoanl_ID
- Month
- Day
- Work_Hours
- Holiday_Hours

I want to count the Work_Hours and the Holiday_Hours for each distinct Employee every month like the table below.
I want to select a period of between 2 month. for example from 'January' 01 to 'March' 03

Persoanl_ID | Name | Month | Work_Hours | Holiday_Hours | TotalWork_Hours|
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
J12345678K | John |**__07__**| **_____150__**|**________08__**| **__________142__**|
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
J12345678K | John |**__08__**| **_____144__**|**_________0__**| **__________144__**|
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
TOTAL____________2___|**____294_|__________8**|__________288

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean with count the sum of hours then you can use the below SQL query :

```
select distinct a.Personal_ID ,a.Name, b.Month, Sum (b.Work_hours),Sum (b.Holiday_hours),Sum (b.Work_hours)+ Sum (b.Holiday_hours) As TotalWork_hours 

from Personale as a , Presenze as b 

where a.Persoanl_ID = b.Persoanl_ID 

Group By b.Month
```

this query will give you result of each month, if you want to split the date as you want I prefer to use DateTime data type which will be easier to filter by date

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select p.Persoanl_ID,
       p.Name,
       pz.Month,
       sum(pz.Work_Hours)    as Work_Hours,
       sum(pz.Holiday_Hours) as Holiday_Hours,
       sum(pz.Work_Hours) + sum(pz.Holiday_Hours) as Total_Hours 
from Personale p, Presenze pz 
where p.Persoanl_ID = pz.Persoanl_ID
  and pz.Month between '01' and '03'
group by p.Persoanl_ID, p.Name, pz.Month;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to see the result for only a specific period, I think following query can give you answer :

```
SELECT b.Persoanl_ID Persoanl_ID ,a.Name Name, b.Month Month, b.Work_Hours 
Work_Hours,   b.Holiday_Hours Holiday_Hours,
(b.Work_hours  + b.Holiday_hours) as TotalWork_Hours
FROM Personale a INNER JOIN Presenze b
ON a.Persoanl_ID = b.Persoanl_ID 
WHERE b.Month BETWEEN 01 AND 03
GROUP BY b.Personal_ID , a.Name , b.Month , b.Work_Hours , b.Holiday_Hours ;
```